# React-Native-Video how to add onPress?

Tags: react-native, video

I'm building mobile app connected with videos, and more like snapchat discover. I want to add onPress function to video, so when user will press on it, it will just go to next video.

So I render video like this.

```
return (
  <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1}}>
    {this.state.buffering && <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>}
    {this.video()}
  </View>
);
```

But when I try to add `Touchableopacity` to it to be able to press to video, video is not visible. I hear the sounds of video but its not visible.

```
return (
  <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1}}>
    {this.state.buffering && <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>}
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.continue.bind(this, 1)}>
      {this.video()}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
```

and video function:

```
return (
  <Video
    source={{uri: 'http://' + this.state.videos[this.state.plamount].video_path}}
    resizeMode="cover"
    paused={this.state.pause}
    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
    onLoad={() => this.setState({buffering: false})}
    repeat={true}
    onError={() => Actions.reset('main')}
  />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer. There can be other answers also but, when I changed

from

```
return (
  <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1}}>
    {this.state.buffering && <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>}
    {this.video()}
  </View>
);
```

to

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.continue.bind(this, 1)} style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1}}>
   {this.state.buffering && <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>}
   {this.continue()}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

it worked.. but anyway, there is still question, why video is not visible, if there is a one more wrapper around video?..